# Why is cloning (in .NET) so difficult?

Tags: .net, theory, cloning

In the past I had the need to clone objects, only to find that they don't implement a `Clone()` method, forcing me to do it by hand (create a new instance and copy all properties from the original to the new one)

Why isn't cloning as easy as duplicating the memory block the object is allocated in, and thus have the `Clone` method in the `object` class, having all classes in .NET inherit it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because that wouldn't perform a deep clone, which is *usually* what clones really need to be. Imagine you have a reference to an array, or a list... simply copying the memory taken by *your object* will simply clone the reference. Any changes to the array will be visible through the clone as well as the original object - so the two objects are still connected, which violated the normal point of cloning.

If you want to implement exactly that functionality, it's easy - that's what [`Object.MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) is for. Most of the time, if it even makes *sense* to clone an object (what does a cloned `NetworkStream` mean?) it makes sense to clone each property... unless it refers to an immutable value already, etc. In other words, this is a naturally hard problem, which is why most types don't support cloning.

If you stick to immutable types wherever possible, it's not so much of an issue... that makes other things harder, admittedly, but it can be *very* powerful in many cases.

Comment: Immutable types are full of win. Also, note that MemberwiseClone is protected or else you could seriously break semantics down to core ECMA-335 specifications like the fact that two System.Type objects are equal iff they reference the same object in memory.

Comment: At the same time I wrote something similar in indifferent words. I think it is a pity that .NET defines "by-ref" and "by-val" on the type (class/struct) and not the field/variable holding it. This is actually the information you need for cloning... and other things.

Comment: @Stefan: That topic is the subject of my research project this semester. It turns out it doesn't cause a fundamental problem with language expressiveness, but the reasoning behind it is not what I originally thought.

Comment: Wouldn't it be conceivable to have a method `DeepClone` which deeply clones assuming all objects implement the `DeeplyCloneable` interface (idea in rough sketches)? Obviously this would affect many many classes and perhaps cloning is not that popular an activity.

Comment: @yar: Yes, there could be a DeepClone method. There just isn't :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, awesome, I'll send an email to the .Net team straight away

Answer (score 8):

Others have already explained about `MemberwiseClone`, but no-one gave the explanation of *why* it is protected. I'll try to give the rationale.

The problem here is that `MemberwiseClone` just blindly copies the state. In many cases, this is undesirable. For example, the object might have a private field which is a reference to a `List`. A shallow copy, such as what `MemberwiseClone` does, would result in new object pointing to the same list - and the class may well be written not expecting the list to be shared with anyone else.

Or an object can have some sort of ID field, generated in constructor - again, when you clone that, you get two objects with the same ID, which may lead to all kinds of weird failures in methods assuming that ID is unique.

Or say you have an object that opens a socket or a file stream, and stores a reference to that. `MemberwiseClone` will just copy the reference - and you can imagine that two objects trying to interleave calls to the same stream isn't going to end well.

In short, "cloning" is not a well-defined operation for arbitrary objects. The fact that memberwise `operator=` is provided for all classes by default in C++ is more of a nuisance, as all too often people forget that it's there, and do not disable it for classes for which copying doesn't make sense, or is dangerous (and there are surprisingly many such classes).

Comment: @Pavel: I hinted at the problem in my comment to Jon before this answer. Your answer is of course the much more complete explanation. :)

Answer (score 4):

There are (at least) two kinds of cloning. Most references talk about *shallow* and *deep* cloning, but in reality there are shades inbetween.

The key problem is the tension between "how much should be copied" and "how much should be shared".

Consider an `Order` object, containing references to a `Customer`, an `Address` and to a `List` of `OrderLines`.

If you wanted to `Clone()` an `Order`, what's involved?

"*Just copying the memory block*" would give you a new `Order`, but one that shared the `Customer`, `Address` and the same `List` of `OrderLines`. (Remember that object members are stored by reference, so when you duplicate the memory block, you end up with two references to the same object).

Clearly, you don't want to share the `List` of `OrderLines` between the two `Order`s. In fact, you probably want to clone each `OrderLine` as well.

If you were working with a general purpose `Clone()` method, how would that method know which members should be recursively cloned, and which should not?

Generally speaking, this is an intractable problem - which is why it's up to individual objects to implement *appropriate semantics for their situation*.

One final note: even when I do create the ability to `Clone()` objects, I don't tend to create a `Clone()` method, instead prefering a **copy constructor** - a constructor that accepts another object as a basis. If you can't find `Clone()`, look for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a thing as [Object.MemberwiseClone(),](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) which does what you describe.  It is making a shallow copy of the object.

It won't do a deep clone automatically... you'll need to call clone on all the member objects manually, etc.

Comment: The only problem with it is that it's a protected method, so unless the class designer decided to expose it, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly implement the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone.aspx) interface in your classes.

However, as the documentation states, the cloning mechanism in [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) does not distinguish between shallow and deep copy.