# Which kind of pointer do I use when?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers, c++-faq

Ok, so the last time I wrote C++ for a living, `std::auto_ptr` was all the std lib had available, and `boost::shared_ptr` was all the rage. I never really looked into the other smart pointer types boost provided. I understand that C++11 now provides some of the types boost came up with, but not all of them.

So does someone have a simple algorithm to determine when to use which smart pointer? Preferably including advice regarding dumb pointers (raw pointers like `T*`) and the rest of the boost smart pointers. (Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139254/140719) would be great).

Comment: See also [std::auto_ptr to std::unique_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3451099/14065)

Comment: I am really hoping someone comes up with a nice handy flowchart like [this STL selection flowchart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container).

Comment: @Als: Oh, that's indeed a nice one! I FAQized it.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's not even close to being a duplicate. The linked question says "When should I use *a* smart pointer" and this question is "When do I use *these* smart pointers?" i.e. this one is categorising the different uses of the standard smart pointers. The linked question does not do this. The difference is seemingly small but it's a big one.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

**Shared ownership:**
The `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` the standard adopted are pretty much the same as their [Boost counterparts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). Use them when you need to share a resource and don't know which one will be the last to be alive. Use `weak_ptr` to observe the shared resource without influencing its lifetime, not to break cycles. Cycles with `shared_ptr` shouldn't normally happen - two resources can't own each other.

Note that Boost additionally offers [`shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm), which might be a suitable alternative to `shared_ptr<std::vector<T> const>`.

Next, Boost offers [`intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html), which are a lightweight solution if your resource offers reference-counted management already and you want to adopt it to the RAII principle. This one was not adopted by the standard.

**Unique ownership:**
Boost also has a [`scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm), which is not copyable and for which you can not specify a deleter. `std::unique_ptr` is `boost::scoped_ptr` on steroids and should be your **default choice when you need a smart pointer**. It allows you to specify a deleter in its template arguments and is *movable*, unlike `boost::scoped_ptr`. It is also fully usable in STL containers as long as you don't use operations that need copyable types (obviously).

Note again, that Boost has an array version: [`scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm), which the standard unified by requiring `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` partial specialization that will `delete[]` the pointer instead of `delete`ing it (with the `default_delete`r). `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` also offers `operator[]` instead of `operator*` and `operator->`.

Note that `std::auto_ptr` is still in the standard, but it is *deprecated*.
`§D.10 [depr.auto.ptr]`

> The class template `auto_ptr` is deprecated. [ *Note:* The class template `unique_ptr` (20.7.1) provides a better solution. *—end note* ]

**No ownership:**
Use dumb pointers (raw pointers) or references for **non-owning references** to resources and when you know that the **resource will outlive** the referencing object / scope. Prefer references and use raw pointers when you need either nullability or resettability.

If you want a non-owning reference to a resource, but you don't know if the resource will outlive the object that references it, pack the resource in a `shared_ptr` and use a `weak_ptr` - you can test if the parent `shared_ptr` is alive with `lock`, which will return a `shared_ptr` that is non-null if the resource still exists. If want to test whether the resource is dead, use `expired`. The two may sound similar, but are very different in the face of concurrent execution, as `expired` only guarantees its return value for that single statement. A seemingly innocent test like

```
if(!wptr.expired())
  something_assuming_the_resource_is_still_alive();
```

is a potential race condition.

Comment: In the case of no ownership, you should probably prefer references to pointers unless you need no ownership *and* resettability where references won't cut it, even then you might want to consider rewriting the original object to be a `shared_ptr` and the non owning pointer to be a `weak_ptr`...

Comment: @Davig: References to pointers are not a good idea. What if they don't get set through the actual owning ptr but through a local or parameter to a function?

Comment: I did not mean *reference to pointer*, but rather reference *instead of* pointer. If there is no ownership, unless you need resettability (or nullability, but nullability without being able to reset would be quite limited) you can use a plain reference rather than a pointer in the first place.

Comment: @David: Ah, I see. :) Yeah, references aren't bad for that, I personally prefer them too in such cases. I'll add them.

Comment: @Xeo: `shared_array<T>` is an alternative to `shared_ptr<T[]>` not to `shared_ptr<vector<T>>`: it cannot grow.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: `shared_ptr` is not specialized for arrays, you'll need to provide your own deleter and it needs to be just `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Well, I meant it acts more like such an hypothetical specialization would (or a normal one with a `default_deleter<T[]>`) than `shared_ptr<vector<T>>` :) I'd also add a note that with `weak_ptr` you can test if the pointer is dead with `expired` or if it's alive with `lock`. `expired` is not fit for testing if the object is alive (hence its name).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Meh, finally came around to updating this answer. Amended with the info on how to test the availability of the resource.

Comment: Raw pointers also allow for manual garbage collection. You can use `release` for unique_ptrs but that doesn't free up the memory.

Comment: @JohnJohn: [`std::unique_ptr<>::reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) is the function to use to destruct the object and deallocate the memory the `unique_ptr` managed, and "garbage collection" implies a lot of things (e.g. groping around memory) that are not necessary in C++.  `release` very deliberately doesn't free up memory because it's a way of saying you want to take ownership from the `unique_ptr` - there wouldn't be anything to take ownership of if `release` destructed/deallocated.

Comment: References cannot be rebound which can be problematic in copy semantics and therefore you can use `std::reference_wrapper`. Unfortunately, the latter is a bit dull since it is currently not possible to override `operator.`

Comment: It's worth noting that the last example is not thread-safe. May not be an issue for a lot of codebases.

Comment: @GregroyCurrie: That's... exactly what I wrote? I said it's an example of a potential race condition.

Comment: Sorry mate, I missed that. Long day.

Comment: Where it says _want to **adopt** it to the RAII principle_ I think it means _want to **adapt** it to the RAII principle_, right?

Answer (score 129):

Deciding what smart pointer to use is a question of *ownership*. When it comes to resource management, object A *owns* object B if it is in control of the lifetime of object B. For example, member variables are owned by their respective objects because the lifetime of member variables is tied to the lifetime of the object. You choose smart pointers based on how the object is owned.

Note that ownership in a software system is separate from ownership as we would think of it outside of software. For example, a person might "own" their home, but that doesn't necessarily mean that a `Person` object has control over the lifetime of a `House` object. Conflating these real world concepts with software concepts is a sure-fire way to program yourself into a hole.

---

If you have sole ownership of the object, use `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

If you have shared ownership of the object...
- If there are no cycles in ownership, use `std::shared_ptr<T>`.
- If there are cycles, define a "direction" and use `std::shared_ptr<T>` in one direction and `std::weak_ptr<T>` in the other.

If the object owns you, but there is potential of having no owner, use normal pointers `T*` (e.g. parent pointers).

If the object owns you (or otherwise has guaranteed existence), use references `T&`.

---

Caveat: Be aware of the costs of smart pointers. In memory or performance limited environments, it could be beneficial to just use normal pointers with a more manual scheme for managing memory.

The costs:

- If you have a custom deleter (e.g. you use allocation pools) then this will incur overhead per pointer that may be easily avoided by manual deletion.
- `std::shared_ptr` has the overhead of a reference count increment on copy, plus a decrement on destruction followed by a 0-count check with deletion of the held object. Depending on the implementation, this can bloat your code and cause performance issues.
- Compile time. As with all templates, smart pointers contribute negatively to compile times.

---

Examples:

```
struct BinaryTree
{
    Tree* m_parent;
    std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree> m_children[2]; // or use std::array...
};
```

A binary tree does not own its parent, but the existence of a tree implies the existence of its parent (or `nullptr` for root), so that uses a normal pointer. A binary tree (with value semantics) has sole ownership of its children, so those are `std::unique_ptr`.

```
struct ListNode
{
    std::shared_ptr<ListNode> m_next;
    std::weak_ptr<ListNode> m_prev;
};
```

Here, the list node owns its next and previous lists, so we define a direction and use `shared_ptr` for next and `weak_ptr` for prev to break the cycle.

Comment: For the example of the binary tree some people would suggest using `shared_ptr<BinaryTree>` for the children and `weak_ptr<BinaryTree>` for the parent relationship.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It depends whether the Tree has value semantics or not. If people are going to be referencing your tree externally even once the source tree is destroyed then yes, shared/weak pointer combo would be best.

Comment: If an objects owns you and is guaranteed to exist then why not a reference.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Possibility of null. I'll add that.

Comment: If you use reference, you cannot ever change the parent, which may or may not hinder the design.  For balancing trees, that would hinder.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I really with there was a way to rebind references, for just this reason.

Comment: +1 but you should add a definition of "ownership" on the first line. I often find myself having to clearly state that it's about life & death of the object, not ownership in a more domain-specific meaning.

Comment: @Klaim: Good comment. I added a definition at the top. Cheers.

Comment: That is very good explanation , but I couldn't understand two things **1:** how is weak ptr different and **2:** what is problem of cycles here? , might be you could give me some motivational problem?  e.g 
`struct ListNode
{
    std::shared_ptr<ListNode> m_next;
    std::shared_ptr<ListNode> m_prev; // no weak ptr , now what?
};`

Comment: @SoulReaper: Cycles are a problem because `shared_ptr` uses reference counting and if two objects reference each other then they'll never decrement their ref counts.

Comment: "If the object owns you" - I can't get what does it mean, can you explain, pls?

Answer (score 21):

Use `unique_ptr<T>` all the time except when you need reference counting, in which case use `shared_ptr<T>` (and for very rare cases, `weak_ptr<T>` to prevent reference cycles). In almost every case, transferrable unique ownership is just fine.

Raw pointers: Good only if you need covariant returns, non-owning pointing which can happen. They're not terrifically useful otherwise.

Array pointers: `unique_ptr` has a specialization for `T[]` which automatically calls `delete[]` on the result, so you can safely do `unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[42]);` for example. `shared_ptr` you'd still need a custom deleter, but you wouldn't need a specialized shared or unique array pointer. Of course, such things are usually best replaced by `std::vector` anyway. Unfortunately `shared_ptr` does not provide an array access function, so you'd still have to manually call `get()`, but `unique_ptr<T[]>` provides `operator[]` instead of `operator*` and `operator->`. In any case, you have to bounds check yourself. This makes `shared_ptr` slightly less user-friendly, although arguably the generic advantage and no Boost dependency makes `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` the winners again.

Scoped pointers: Made irrelevant by `unique_ptr`, just like `auto_ptr`.

There's really nothing more to it. In C++03 without move semantics this situation was very complicated, but in C++11 the advice is very simple.

There are still uses for other smart pointers, like `intrusive_ptr` or `interprocess_ptr`. However, they're *very* niche and completely unnecessary in the general case.

Comment: Also, raw pointers for iteration.  And for output parameter buffers, where the buffer is owned by the caller.

Comment: Hmm, the way I read that, it's situations which are both covariant return and non-owning.  A rewrite might be good if you meant the union rather than intersection.  I'd also say that iteration is worth special mention also.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` provides `operator[]` instead of `operator*` and `operator->`. It's true that you still need to do bound checking yourself though.

Answer (score 13):

Cases of when to use `unique_ptr`:

- Factory methods
- Members that are pointers (pimpl included)
- Storing pointers in stl containters (to avoid moves)
- Use of large local dynamic objects

Cases of when to use `shared_ptr`:

- Sharing objects across threads
- Sharing objects in general

Cases of when to use `weak_ptr`:

- Large map that acts as a general reference (ex. a map of all open sockets)

Feel free to edit and add more

Comment: I actually like your answer more as you give scenarios.