# Pointers and memory leaks

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Is there anything wrong with the following program? Do I have to delete the pointers so I don't have a memory leaks?

Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x=2, y=3;
int *p,*q;
int **pp;

cout<<x<<","<<y<<endl;//x=2,y=3
p=&x;
q=&y;
cout<<*p<<","<<*q<<endl;//*p=2,*q=3
p=new int [5];
p[2]=9;
q=p+x;
p[0]=8;

cout<<*p<<","<<*q<<endl;//*p=8,*q=9

pp=&p;

cout<<pp[0][2]<<endl;//pp[0][2]=9

q=new int;
p=q;
*p=5;
*q=7;

cout<<*p<<","<<*q<<endl;//*p=7,*q=7
delete p;
p=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: And code like this is why everybody seems to hate C++ and think it's full of leaks.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: The code as presented can be rewritten with no pointers at all. Unless you're learning how pointers work, or absolutely need them, don't use them. http://www.tinyurl.com/dont-use-pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating memory for p and q:

```
p=new int [5];
/* ... */
q=new int;
```

But you are only freeing p using an invalid operator, since arrays should be deleted using delete[]. You should at some point free both p and q using:

```
delete[] p;
delete q;
```

Note that since you are making your pointers point to the other pointer's allocated buffer, you might have to check which `delete` operator corresponds to which `new` operation.

You should use `delete[]` on the buffer allocated with `new[]` and `delete` with the buffer allocated with `new`.

Comment: `p` and `q` point to the same object when that `delete` is used.

Comment: The code is incorrect because OP already lost the pointer to dynamically allocated array, `p` doesn't point to what `new []` allocated but it points to what `new`allocated.

Comment: Yeah, he's mixing his pointers, i hadn't see that. Done some edition on the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You do have a memory leak.
Simplest rule to do this is:

**Count the number of `new` & `new []` in your program and you should have exactly same number of `delete` and `delete []`respectively.**

Your program has a `new []` and a `new` but only a single `delete` so you are leaking the memory allocated through `new []`.

**Makeshift Solution:**
You should be calling `delete []` on exactly the same address returned by `new []`

**Most appropriate Solution:**
You should never manually manage dynamic memory You should be using **[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and [Smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when)** to do this for you, it is the ideal and the most appropriate C++ way to do this.