# _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserdata) AND _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

I just "finished" my AVL tree implementation and went to test what previously worked with a normal binary search tree. But now I am getting these assertion errors when the bsTree constructor is called.

_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) is first and if I continue windows spits the next one out.
_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserdata)

TYPE is defined in a type.h as Signal* I plan to change this to use templates or whatever for a polymorphic implementation but this seemed simple for initial setup.

main execution:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include"binSearchTree.h"
;
using namespace std;

int main(){

string word;
int i = 0;
ifstream book ("AV1611Bible.txt");

if(book.is_open()){

    book >> word;

    bsTree* tree = new bsTree(new Signal(word));

    while( book.good()){
        book >> word;
        tree->addValue(new Signal(word));
        //cout << word;
        cout << i++ << "\n";
    }
    book.close();
}


return 0;
}
```

bsTree Constructors:

```
#include"binSearchTree.h"

;
using namespace std;

bsTree::bsTree(){

root = new Node();
size = 0;
}

bsTree::bsTree(TYPE v){
root = new Node(v);
size = 0;
}

bsTree::~bsTree(){
delete root;
}
```

Signal constructors:

```
#include"signal.h"


using namespace std;


Signal::Signal(){
signal = "";
count = 0;
prob = 0;
}

Signal::Signal(string s){
Signal(s,0);
}

Signal::Signal(string s, double p){
signal = s;
count = 0;
prob = p;
}

Signal::Signal(string s, int n, double p){
signal = s;
count = n;
prob = p;
 }

Signal::~Signal(){
delete(&signal);
delete(&count);
delete(&prob);
}
```

Comment: Aside from the [missing copy ctor and copy assignment operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722), there's just so much *wrong* in this code... First, stop [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721). Second, don't `new` everything, this is not Java or C#. Third, never ever `delete` non-pointers! (You didn't show the header, but I'm pretty sure `signal`, `count` and `prob` are *not* pointers. Fourth, use [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/106508) *if* you have to use dynamic allocation (and [use the right one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8706192)).

Comment: You also didn't show the definition of `Node`, which I can almost see also not abiding the rule of three.

Comment: About namespace, I didn't have them everywhere and then Visual studio complained. And stopped when i put them in. I figured out the problem a little while after I posted. XEO is right, my deconstructor was causing the problem with the deletes. I'll look into the rule of three. 

I originally learned on java and dont have any formal training with C++. Just trying to get a feel for things.

Comment: Is there a way to mark Xeo's comment as the answer? The option below doesn't seem exactly correct.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Xeo was correct. The destructors were accessing memory that it didn't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown above has **Undefined Behavior**, due to e.g. `delete` of something that was not allocated with `new`, and then *anything* can happen, including whatever behavior it is that you see (which you forgot to describe)