# std::auto_ptr vs. std::tr1::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, std, auto-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which kind of pointer do I use when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when)

I read that `std::auto_ptr` is obsolete, so you must use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` instead. As I read difference is `std::tr1::shared_ptr` have reference counting, while `std::auto_ptr` haven't, so copying or assigning makes the resource changing its owner, with the source giving the ownership to the destination. Is it the only difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smart pointer that closest matches the single ownership semantics of `auto_ptr` is [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). This should be used preferentially over `std::shared_ptr`, if available. See [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-unique_ptr).

Comment: @Fanael thanks for spotting that!