# Is there a good C++ memory management tutorial available, that covers shared_ptr, scoped_ptr, and weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which kind of pointer do I use when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when)

I'm a former C++ programmer, turned .NET programmer.  My knowledge of C++ memory management dates back to the early 2000's, and I haven't kept up with C++11 features.  I've been asked to do a new project in C++, and I'm hoping to find a good tutorial on modern C++ memory management using shared_ptr, weak_ptr, and scoped_ptr.  Something covering common patterns and best practices would be ideal.  Do you have any pointers for me?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `scoped_ptr` is part of Boost, not the C++ standard library. The closest one in the standard library is `unique_ptr`.