# unique_ptr to char* conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I used to allocate memory in my C++ project with new

```
char* buffer = new char [size];
...
delete[] buffer;
```

and I'd really like to move forward and use `unique_ptr`, like this

```
unique_ptr<char[]>buffer(new char[size]);
```

but then I use `istream& get (char* s, streamsize n);` which takes `char*` as a first argument, so what should I do? I've tried to cast types, but failed. I also know I can use `vector<char>` instead of pointers, but I don't really like to use it. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use unique\_ptr for ownership and raw pointer otherwise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555441/use-unique-ptr-for-ownership-and-raw-pointer-otherwise)

Comment: When in doubt about how to use a class, it's a good idea to consult some documentation about it, such as [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get).

Comment: you shouldn't use `new`, use [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: What is the point against `std::vector<char>` or even `std::string`? Vector is a block of continuous memory. It is exactly what you should be using. Except for statically allocated arrays, there you could go with `std::array`.

Answer (score 14):

The class `std::unique_ptr` has a method called `get()` to access the underlying pointer: use that.

```
unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[size]);
...
myIstream.get(buffer.get(), n);
```

Comment: But when I try to pass the pointer to library function, fetching from get(), the application crashes.

Comment: That could be for all sorts of reasons depending on the details, not necessarily related to the original question. Perhaps you could post your own new question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` specialization for arrays. How to use it in your case in shown by Smeehey in his answer.

But, as of Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++" Item 18 (Emphasis mine):

> The existence of std::unique_ptr for arrays should be of only intellectual interest to you, because **std::array, std::vector, and std::string are virtually always better data structure choices than raw arrays.**

So, use the  classes that are made for this purpose instead of hacking your way there with `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use `vector` rather than `unique_ptr`, but using `unique_ptr` has it's own benefits.
I also faced the same issue earlier, in which I had a buffer allocated using `unique_ptr` and passed it as a argument to read function. The only way to get rid of this is using the `get()` method which converts the `unique_ptr` to `char*`. 
Also make sure you have `#include <memory>` to avoid other errors which I faced.

Thanks!