# Reference data members and move constructor

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, move-semantics

Assuming the following code:

```
class ChannelHandle;
class SessionHandle;

typedef ChannelHandle& ChannelHandleRef;
typedef SessionHandle& SessionHandleRef;

class RemoteChannelHandle
{
public:
    RemoteChannelHandle(
        ChannelHandleRef pChannelHandle, SessionHandleRef pSessionHandle);
    RemoteChannelHandle(RemoteChannelHandle&&);
    ~RemoteChannelHandle();

    void CloseChannel();

#ifndef _MSC_VER
    RemoteChannelHandle& operator=(RemoteChannelHandle&&) = delete;
    RemoteChannelHandle(RemoteChannelHandle const&) = delete;
    RemoteChannelHandle& operator=(RemoteChannelHandle const&) = delete;
#endif
private:
    LIBSSH2_CHANNEL* channel;
    ChannelHandleRef channelHandle;
    SessionHandleRef sessionHandle;
};

RemoteChannelHandle::RemoteChannelHandle(
    ChannelHandleRef pChannelHandle, SessionHandleRef pSessionHandle)
    : channel(nullptr), channelHandle(pChannelHandle), sessionHandle(pSessionHandle)
{
    // OPEN SSH CHANNEL
}

RemoteChannelHandle::~RemoteChannelHandle()
{
    try
    {
        CloseChannel();
    }
    catch (...)
    { }
}

void RemoteChannelHandle::CloseChannel()
{
    if (channel == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    // CLOSE SSH CHANNEL. THROW IF SOMETHING GOES WRONG

    channel = nullptr;
}
```

- RemoteChannelHandle opens an SSH channel, but the cleanup requires
  two steps (close + free). The first step is performed in
  `~RemoteChannelHandle()`, but the second will be performed in
  ChannelHandle's dtor; hence the data member `channelHandle`, since
  we'll need to inject `channel` into it. This reference could be
  eliminated by performing both steps in `~RemoteChannelHandle()`.
- `sessionHandle` holds the `LIBSSH2_SESSION*` necessary to open the SSH
  channel. Since I don't want to pass `LIBSSH2_SESSION*` around, this
  reference can't be eliminated.

The problem happens when I define a move ctor for RemoteChannelHandle. I need to clear the members of the "moved from" instance. However, there's no way to clear the reference. So, what to do here?

1. Use `(const) std::shared_ptr` instead of references? I could even use
   naked pointers, as there's no ownership involved. I realize there's some debate
   regarding the use of references as data members, but apart from the
   move ctor, I foresee no other scenario where I would need to reseat
   the handles  (which is why I used references in the first place).
2. Leave the references as they are, and create a "state" data member
   specifically to check if the object is in a valid state (I can use `channel != nullptr`
   for this purpose)?
3. Any other idea?

I've searched for alternatives to this, and found no clear answer. Which could mean there's actually no clear answer, of course.

Thanks for your time.

Edit (in reply to Mankarse):
ChannelHandle exists solely to perform step 2 of cleanup. Here's a simplified definition:

```
class ChannelHandle
{
public:
    ChannelHandle();
    ChannelHandle(ChannelHandle&&);
    ~ChannelHandle();

#ifndef _MSC_VER
    ChannelHandle& operator=(ChannelHandle&&) = delete;
    ChannelHandle(ChannelHandle const&) = delete;
    ChannelHandle& operator=(ChannelHandle const&) = delete;
#endif

    LIBSSH2_CHANNEL* GetChannel() { return channel; }
    void SetChannel(LIBSSH2_CHANNEL* pChannel) { channel = pChannel; }

    void FreeChannel();
private:
    LIBSSH2_CHANNEL* channel;
};
```

SessionHandle is an RAII encapsulation for a `LIBSSH2_SESSION*`. It calls `libssh2_session_init()` on ctor and `libssh2_session_free()` on dtor. Other similar classes take care of other steps of the SSH session's init/cleanup, but this is where we get the `LIBSSH2_SESSION*` from libssh2, and SessionHandle owns it. Once again, a simplified definition:

```
class SessionHandle
{
public:
    SessionHandle();
    SessionHandle(SessionHandle&&);
    ~SessionHandle();

    void CloseSession();
    LIBSSH2_SESSION* GetSession() { return session; }

#ifndef _MSC_VER
    SessionHandle& operator=(SessionHandle&&) = delete;
    SessionHandle(SessionHandle const&) = delete;
    SessionHandle& operator=(SessionHandle const&) = delete;
#endif
private:    
    LIBSSH2_SESSION *session;
};
```

Comment: How are `ChannelHandle` and `SessionHandle` defined, and what do they do?

Comment: Since you have a lvalue reference member, the lvalue reference and the classes containing it is not a temporary.  The move ctor may never get invoked anyway no matter how you define it.  The copy ctor may get picked all the time anyway.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8706254/819272

Comment: @emsr You could be right, I'm still in the early stages of using these classes, so my tested scenarios are still limited. From my tests with gcc (tests with VC++ to follow), return by value invokes nothing, so it's probably RVO at work. The scenario I'm testing now, and for which I wanted the move ctor, is moving objects of these classes from/to containers.

Comment: @rhalbersma Well, two "votes" for pointers instead of references in this scenario.

Comment: references if you can, pointers if you must

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered the question yourself:

> I could even use naked pointers, as there's no ownership involved.

Comment: True, but am I wrong in assuming that, if it wasn't for the move ctor, implementation with references would be the Right Way(TM)? I've been away from C++ for a few years, but back when I learned it "Always prefer references" was mantra-like.

Comment: @PCaetano: References are better than pointers if you don't need to nullify them or change the target, because they prevent you from accidentally doing those things. But if you do need to do those things (as you do here), then you can't use them.

Comment: Using references eliminates ambiguity, whereas pointers require something more - e.g., a comment, a typedef, a wrapper. I've just read proposal N3514, and it could be a step in the right direction, by creating a standard way of expressing this relationship.