# Java-style memory management in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

What is the best way to use Java-style references in C++? Will using `shared_ptr` for all classes and structs be the correct equivalent?

Comment: Java and C++ are different languages. They are not equivalent and take different coding styles. Trying to code in C++ as if it was Java is not an appropriate way to write C++

Comment: shared_ptr (and its siblings) is the correct way to get (almost) effortless memory management in c++

Comment: No. Java has extra defenses against cycles that `shared_ptr` lacks. in C++ the recommendation is to not use a dynamic allocation unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @user4581301 any non trivial C++ app has dynamic memory allocation

Comment: There is no mechanical translation from Java to C++. Some uses of Java references can be appropriately implemented by shared pointers, but I'd say that's a very small minority, since shared pointers only have a very niche use in C++. There are many other ways of passing arguments in C++ that will be better in many situations.

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote the comments. Why is the answer abour RAII downvoted, is it wrong?

Comment: its not really relevant to your question

Comment: @KerrekSB could you expand on it a bit, why do they only have a niche use only?

Comment: @pm100 RAII is idiom for exception safe resource management. Why it is not relevant? It is even better since it also manages other resources besides memory like sockets, locks or file descriptors.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Probably because the question isn't about the C++ idioms for exception safe resource management.

Comment: @Utka: Because it's very rare that an object truly has *shared* ownership. In the overwhelming majority of cases, an object has a clear, unique owner.

Comment: What is the question about if it is not about resource management in C++?

Comment: one of the problems I often face is that I realize later on, that I need polymorphic objects instead of my original ones. Which means I need pointers instead of objects and raw pointers seemed (to me) to become unpopular in modern C++.

Comment: @Utka There are different ways of solving that problem, but imitating java isn't a good one. It doesn't play to C++'s strengths.

Comment: @pm100 Agree, and it looks like OP has found a good case for dynamic allocation. Utka: Give this a read: [Which kind of pointer do I use when?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when)

Comment: @ÖöTiib I think resource management is relevant, as long as it can solve the problem. To me, Java references have two main properties - they will be automatically freed and they are polymorphic. They are also "easy" to use, whereas I would  say, that  writing a wrapper for every class (possibly even for standard ones) is not an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) for understanding C++ smart pointers.

Now, if by 'Java-style references' you mean you want to pass an object or struct into a method and that passed in object is not a *copy* of the object, but rather a *reference* to the object, then simply use *pass by reference*.

Ex:

```
void foo( int& ref, int val)
{
   ref = ref + 1; // pass by reference
   val = val + 1; // pass by value
}
...
int main()
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 10;
   foo(a, b);
   // a is being passed by reference so foo directly modifies a
   std::cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b;
   // output would be: a = 11 b = 10
}
```