# Generic Interface inheriting Non-Generic One C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

This is class design question.

I have main abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractBlockRule
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public abstract List<IRestriction> Restrictions {get;};
}

public interface IRestriction{}

public interface IRestriction<T>:IRestriction where T:struct
{
    T Limit {get;} 
}

public TimeRestriction:IRestriction<TimeSpan>
{
    public TimeSpan Limit{get;set;}
}

public AgeRestriction:IRestriction<int>
{
    public int Limit{get;set;}
}

public class BlockRule:AbstractBlockRule
{
    public virtual List<IRestriction> Restrictions {get;set;}
}

BlockRule rule=new BlockRule();
TimeRestriction t=new TimeRestriction();
AgeRestriction a=new AgeRestriction();

rule.Restrictions.Add(t);
rule.Restrictions.Add(a);
```

I have to use non-generic Interface IRestriction just to avoid specifying generic type T in main abstract class. I'm very new to generics. Can some one let me know how to better design this thing?

Comment: It is hard to improve your code, for me. The non-generic base interface could have a property `ValueType BoxedLimit {get;}` if you wanted, but I am not sure it is useful. After all, why do you need a `List<>` of objects of different types?

Comment: (Of course, the obvious idea to make the generic interface covariant, `IRestriction<out T>`, is not useful when you use it with value types (structs), since C# and .NET do not support covariance with value types.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't make either the abstract class, or the method, generic. Is `Limit` a minimum or maximum? If so perhaps `IComparable` would be more useful.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your approach is typical (for example, IEnumerable<T> implements IEnumerable like this). If you want to provide maximum utility to consumers of your code, it would be nice to provide a non-generic accessor on the non-generic interface, then hide it in the generic implementation. For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractBlockRule
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public abstract List<IRestriction> Restrictions { get; set; }
}

public interface IRestriction
{
    object Limit { get; }
}

public interface IRestriction<T> : IRestriction 
    where T:struct
{
    // hide IRestriction.Limit
    new T Limit {get;} 
}

public abstract class RestrictionBase<T> : IRestriction<T>
    where T:struct
{
    // explicit implementation
    object IRestriction.Limit
    {
        get { return Limit; }
    }

    // override when required
    public virtual T Limit { get; set; }
}

public class TimeRestriction : RestrictionBase<TimeSpan>
{
}

public class AgeRestriction : RestrictionBase<TimeSpan>
{
}

public class BlockRule : AbstractBlockRule
{
    public override List<IRestriction> Restrictions { get; set; }
}
```

I also showed using a base restriction class here, but it is not required.

Answer (score 5):

The runtime treats `IRestriction<TimeSpan>` and `IRestriction<int>` as different distinct classes (they even have their own set of static variables). In your case the only classes common to both `IRestriction<TimeSpan>` and `IRestriction<int>` in the inheritance hierarchy are `IRestriction` and `object`.

So indeed, having a list of `IRestriction` is the only sensible way to go.

---

As a side note: you have a property `Limit` in there that you might want to access regardless of whether you're dealing with an `IRestriction<TimeSpan>` or `IRestriction<int>`. What I would do in this case is to define another property `object Limit { get; }` on `IRestriction`, and hide it in the actual implementation. Like this:

```
public interface IRestriction
{
    object Limit { get; }
}

public interface IRestriction<T> : IRestriction
    where T : struct
{
    new T Limit { get; set; }
}

public class TimeRestriction : IRestriction<TimeSpan>
{
    public TimeSpan Limit { get; set; }

    // Explicit interface member:
    // This is hidden from IntelliSense
    // unless you cast to IRestriction.
    object IRestriction.Limit
    {
        get
        {
            // Note: boxing happens here.
            return (object)Limit;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can access `Limit` as `object` on all your `IRestriction` when you don't care what type it is. For example:

```
foreach(IRestriction restriction in this.Restrictions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(restriction.Limit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are contracts that need to be followed by the entity that implements the contract.

You have created two contract with the same name `IRestriction`

As far as I can see, what you are basically may need is a flag for classes that can be restricted, which should implement the `IRestriction` non-generic interface.

The second interface seems to be restrictable objects that also contain a limit property.
Hence the definition of the second `IRestriction` interface can be `ILimitRestriction` or whatever name suits your business needs.

Hence `ILimitRestriction` can inherit from `IRestriction` which would mark classes inheriting `ILimitRestriction` still objects of `IRestriction`

```
public abstract class AbstractBlockRule
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public abstract List<IRestriction> Restrictions {get;};
}

public interface IRestriction{}

public interface IRestrictionWithLimit<T>:IRestriction where T:struct
{
    T Limit {get;} 
}

public TimeRestriction:IRestrictionWithLimit<TimeSpan>
{
    public TimeSpan Limit{get;set;}
}

public AgeRestriction:IRestrictionWithLimit<int>
{
    public int Limit{get;set;}
}

public class BlockRule:AbstractBlockRule
{
    public virtual List<IRestriction> Restrictions {get;set;}
}
```