# Is this the correct way C# set getter and setter on class property?

Tags: c#

As you can see under I have create getter and setter for class property.
I'm wondering, is it fine to set it up like I did under? I didn't use the private variable in the get, is it fine or should I use it?
Could someone correct me how my class in this case, should look like, if my approach is wrong? The class is CloneAble

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }

private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Id == null)
            return null;
        else
            return this.Id+ "/" + this.Code;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._name != value)
        {
            this._name= value;
        }
    }
}

public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Id == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

The class is Cloneable:

```
public object Clone()
{
    var elem= new Element();

    this.SetPropertyValues(elem);

    return elem;
}

private void SetPropertyValues(elem)
{
    var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite && (p.PropertyType.IsValueType || p.PropertyType.IsEnum || p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(System.String))));

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfo)
    {
        if (property.CanWrite)
        {
            property.SetValue(elem, property.GetValue(this, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Name supposed to mean ? you set private field _name it with any input you give to setter Name, *but*, when you get it it doesn't give back _name, but a combination of Id and Code. 
While this is syntaxicly perfectly valid, I'm not sure what's your goal here. How do you use `_name` in the rest of the class ?

Comment: also, last point is simply `return this.Id != null`

Comment: When you use `get; set;` you cannot see the private field in your code but internally a private field is used. So it really depends on what you prefer. But the code inside your getters and setters is unnecessary. For example `IsValid` whill always return true as an Integer cannot be null.

Comment: as it stands the setter does nothing so shouldn't be there (the _name field is never referenced).Do you need a setter?  You could just use a get only property.

Comment: Getters and setters exist specifically to allow custom logic when getting or setting properties, so the fact that you have custom logic is fine per se. It is also not an error to return a calculated value from a getter - you decide whether it is okay in your case or it would be better to cache the value. What is not fine is that the getter returns not what the setter sets, which is highly confusing.

Comment: (this.Id==null) results in a compiler warning _"Warning CS0472 The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'")

Comment: Shouldn't this be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here - you can set Name to one thing, but when you get the Name back it is something different?

Comment: What you could do is put an null check in the Setter for value. If ``` this._name != value``` then ```this._name = value```, but what if ```value``` is ```null```? It depends on your business logic what you want to achieve and then you will know what is appropriate.

Comment: The reason I have a setter in name is because the class is cloneable and I get an error which say it cannot set value on Name, since it has no setter, if i remove it. Lets say if I change the Code part, then it should also change the name.

Comment: @FredrikLinger You can circumvent the cloning issue by using a [Copy-Contructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) instead (for example). And here is an interesting alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345529/982149

Comment: @Fildor I have udated the description with my clone method.

Comment: There you go. Much too complicated. Just make a new instance and copy the values. You can also access private fields there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get rid of your struggles by simplifying the Clone Method:

```
// Private parameterized CTOR
private Element( int id, string code ) 
{ 
    this.Id = id;
    this.Code = code;
}

// Simplyfied Clone
public object Clone()
{
    return new Element(Id, Code);
}
```

Now you can have the readonly Property Name *and* Clone:

```
public string Name => $"{Id}/{Code}";
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but what is the utility of `_name`? You can set its value but not the opposite. In addition, creating `IsValid` is not very useful, as `Id` is a public attribute; you could simply create a method whose value is `this.Id != wrongValue` and make `Id` private.

The result would be the following:

```
private int Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }

private readonly int IMPOSSIBLE_ID = -1000;

private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get {
        return (this.Id == null) ? null : this.Id+ "/" + this.Code;
    }
    set {
        if (this._name != value)
            this._name= value;
    }
}

public bool IsValid() => return this.Id != IMPOSSIBLE_ID;
```

**UPDATE : now `Id` is a nullable integer**

```
private int? Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }

private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get {
        return (this.Id == null) ? null : this.Id+ "/" + this.Code;
    }
    set {
        if (this._name != value)
            this._name= value;
    }
}

public bool IsValid() => return this.Id != null;
```

Comment: an int cannot be null

Comment: (this.Id==null) results in a compiler warning _"Warning CS0472 The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'")

Comment: this still doesn't explain the use of the setter for name.

Comment: Let's say if Id is a nullable int. How would you correct my code to make it correct?

By the way I have set it up, is it fine to do it like this?

Comment: If it is nullable then `IMPOSSIBLE_ID` is useless; you can delete l.4 and change last line to `public bool IsValid() => return this.Id != null;`. As for Name attribute... I don't know exactly how would you like to use it so I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: @Fildor The default value for a nullable is `null`, so `IsValid()` returns `false` unless we define a value for `Id`.

Comment: @0009laH There is no nullable in your example code.   Ah wait. In your comment. OK, Nevermind.

Comment: Could I set the private variable as combination of id and code in the getter and return the private variable there? Would it be more correct? I think the parsing is a bit overkill for my case, as I kind of need the setter only because of the Cloneable type...

Comment: How did you implement cloning @FredrikLinger?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `int Id` can never be `null` since `int` is `struct`; that's why `this.Id == null` *is always* `true`. You can either make `Id` be *nullable*:

```
 public int? Id { get; set; }
```

or change `this.Id == null` into, say, `this.Id == 0`

```
 // Let Id be nullable 
 public int? Id { get; set; }
 public string Code { get; set; }
```

Since `Name` can be easily computed, you don't want `_name`. Another issue with `Name` setter: you can assign, say, `"bla-bla-bla"` to `Name` then *read it again*
and get something unexpected:

```
 var demo = MyClass();

 // "0/"
 Console.WriteLine(demo.Name);

 demo.Name = "123/Test";

 // "0/" instead of expected "123/Test";
 Console.WriteLine(demo.Name);
```

That's why I suggest either to *remove* the setter:

```
 public string Name {
   get {
     return Id.HasValue
       ? $"{Id}/{Code}"
       : ""; // often, it's better return an empty string, not null
   }
 }
```

Or implement some kind of *parsing*:

```
 public string Name {
   get {
     return Id.HasValue
       ? $"{Id}/{Code}"
       : ""; // often, it's better return an empty string, not null
   }
   set {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
       Id = null;
       Code = ""; // often, it's better return an empty string, not null
     } 
     else {
       string[] parts = string.Split(new char[] {'/'}, 2);

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parts[0])) {
         Id = null;
         Code = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : ""; 
       }
       else if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out int id)) {
         Id = id;
         Code = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : ""; 
       } 
       else 
         throw new FormatException("Name is inincorrect format.");
     }
   }
 }
```

Finally, `IsValid` can be shortened into

```
 public bool IsValid => Id.HasValue;
```

Comment: The reason I have a setter in name is because the class is cloneable and I get an error which say it cannot set value on Name, since it has no setter, if i  remove it.

Lets say if I change the Code part, then it should also change the name.

Comment: If the class implements `ICloneable` you should either check interface implementation  (remove `.Name = this.Name;` fragment) or implement parsing within `set`

Comment: Could you give me an example how it should look like? :)

Comment: @Fredrik Linger: Sorry, but I've provided `Name`  `set` which *parses* value provided and assignes `Id`  as well as `Code`. Please, see my second (much longer) version of `Name` property