# How to separate a variable from the list it gets its value from c#

Tags: c#, list

So I have a list:

```
List<Class> myList = new List<Class>
```

I create an object that is equal to one of the items so that I can update it:

```
Class item = myList[0]
```

I also have a copy of the item (so that I can restore any changes if needed):

```
Class copyItem = myList[0]
```

When I update the `item` the item in `myList` also updates, which is what I want.

**But I don't want this to happen with the `copyItem`, how do I make it so that the copy doesn't reference the `myList`?**

Comment: Getting `myList[0]` does not make (or get) a copy of anything.  It gets a reference to the same object.

Comment: If you get them *the same way*, why do you expect them to behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Class` class (which, by the way, is a terrible name for a class) is simple enough, you can write a copy constructor to help you create a new copy of the instance.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public Person(Person person) { Name = person.Name; City = person.City; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In your main:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person() { Name = "Jane", City = "London" },
    new Person() { Name = "Mike", City = "NY" }
};

var item = people[0];
var copy = new Person(people[0]);

item.City = "LA";
```

Now;

> item.City = "LA"

But

> copy.City = "London"

Obviously this approach may not be suitable if your class has a ton of properties or a complex nested structure.

In such a situation you'll need to think about deep/shallow cloning, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345389/copy-constructor-versus-clone) is a good read.

Answer (score 5):

I think the main issue here is one of expectations:

```cs
Class item = myList[0]
```

does **not** create an object (assuming that `Class` is a `class`, i.e. a reference-type); it makes a copy of the *reference* and assigns it to the local variable `item`, but: the reference points to the same, single object.

The key here is that there is *only one object*; you have only copied the *reference*, and that's just (essentially) a pointer. It doesn't matter which reference/pointer you use: any change you make still impacts the same object, and you won't have a backup.

For what you need, you'd need to look into creating a clone (deep clone or shallow clone, depending on your needs) of the object.

Alternatively, note that the problems you describe don't apply to *value types*, but they have *much more complex* usage constraints that (unless treated very carefully) will trip you up in other subtle ways.

Comment: Nice explanation...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really reference `myList`, only a member of `myList`. You will probably need to implement `Clone()` for `Class`.

Comment: It should be noted that Microsoft recommends against implementing `ICloneable`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this below so that you can create new object.

```
Class copyItem = new Class()
```

Now assign properties from myList[0] like below

```
copyItem.propery1 = myList[0].property1
copyItem.propery2 = myList[0].property2
```

Please see Marc Gravell answer for more explanation.